# VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Tried all but Still getting error

Tags: blockchain, ether, revert

Have tried all things, I am running the following program on Remix there i use Injected web3 Metamask but continously getting error when I call convertToUsd function and same code run through truffle and Ganache. Any help will be appreciated cuz i had give too much time but no solution.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "contracts/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract VaurseWallet {
    mapping(address => uint256) private balances;
    uint256 private vosCoinRate;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    constructor(address _priceFeed, uint256 _vosCoinRate) {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeed);
        vosCoinRate = _vosCoinRate;
    }

    function creditWallet() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 amount, address payable recipient) public {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= amount, "Insufficient balance");
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        recipient.transfer(amount);
    }

    function checkBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[msg.sender];
    }

    function convertToUSD(uint256 amount) public view returns (uint256) {
        require(amount > 0, "Amount must be greater than 0");
        (,int256 price,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        uint256 decimals = uint256(priceFeed.decimals());
        return (amount * uint256(price) / (6 ** decimals));
    }

    // function buyVosCoin(uint256 amount) public {
    //     require(balances[msg.sender] >= amount * vosCoinRate, "Insufficient balance");
    //     balances[msg.sender] -= amount * vosCoinRate;
    //     // Here you can write code to buy Voscoin from a particular exchange
    // }
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Is `priceFeed` a valid contract? The function `convertToUSD` is quite simple it only interacts with the price feed. If there's an error it should be in that interaction.

Comment: Yeah i figure it out. The problem is i'm not forking with sepolia chain and the price feed Address is outdated.